# IntelliJ gives different errors every time i restart my PC

Tags: java, intellij-idea, restart, intellij-14

[image: java icons]

Following things/errors happen everytime i restart my pc

1. it changes the theme to IntelliJ from Dracula.
2. it can't open project, when they open, it won't show me the classes
3. As you can see in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDJcu.png), it can't load the class/interface icons, and the
   compiler doesn't work neither

If this info can help:
It started to happen after i upgraded my laptop to SSD

Comment: It sounds like perhaps some system files for IntelliJ may actually have been damaged or altered.  Either that, or SSD has something against vampires :-)

Comment: In your IntelliJ installation/bin directory there should be a file named `idea.properties` can you please check where it is looking for the 'idea.config.path' and 'idea.system.path', by default it should be `${user.home}/.IntelliJIdea/config`. If so, when you restart, can you see if the files there are being changed after restart?

Comment: @dubes , just tried it and nothing changed.. :/ Should i maybe just reinstall it?

Comment: @DoganCan would advice to reinstall, this issue is not normal. Let me know if reinstall doesn't help, can look at the logs with you in a chat

Answer (score 0):

Considering point 1 and 2 check the logs of the intellij in the idea.log file

Considering point 3. It means that content root for project is not set
Go to "Project Structure" -> Modules

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-content-roots.html

Comment: I tried my best dude, and didn't work for me. But thanks any way.